# Select rows WHERE column = value or column is null (current solution is sloppy and slow)

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently developing a web form that `Inserts customer data into a database`. Before insertion, the database needs to be `queried for duplicates`. The fields I'm checking are `Name, Shipping Address, and Billing Address`. `Name`is a `required field`, and at least `one address is also required`. Right now my (very messy) code looks like this:

```
string partialQuery;
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);

if(/*both addresses fillied out*/)  {
    partialQuery = "BillingAddress=@BillingAddress AND ShippingAddress=@ShippingAddress";
}
else if(/*only billing address is filled out*/)  {
    partialQuery = "BillingAddress=@BillingAddress AND ShippingAddress IS NULL";
}
else if(/*only shipping address is filled out*/)  {
    partialQuery = "BillingAddress IS NULL AND ShippingAddress=@ShippingAddress";
}
else  {  throw new Exception("error...");  }

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Name=@Name AND " + partalQuery, sqlConn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillingAddress", BillingAddress.Text, null);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShippingAddress", ShippingAddress.Text, null);
```

I've been trying to find a more efficent way of doing this with one SQL command and I thought that this code would do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
 WHERE Name = @Name
 AND BillingAccount = ISNULL(@BillingAccount, BillingAccount)
 AND ShippingAccount = ISNULL(@ShippingAccount, ShippingAccount)
```

The idea was to check if @BillingAccount / @ShippingAccount is null, and if they are, the expression would evaluate to BillingAccount = BillingAccount / ShippingAccount = ShippingAccount (which would then evaluate to true).

The problem I ran into is that while *value* = *value* is true, *null* = *null* is false, making the entire WHERE clause false (because I'm using ANDs).

I'm not really sure where to go from hear.

*Side note*: If you're wondering why my AddWithValue method uses 3 parameters, it's an extension method that convert c# null values into SQL null values.  Code is hear if you're interested:  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/310792/Handling-null-values-in-SqlParameter-parameter-obj

Comment: What do you mean by "slow"? Your current solution might not be so concise, but definitely generates the most efficient SQL for those cases.

Comment: @IvanStoev my speed issues might not be from the query itself.  I've only got 1 gig of memory on my test server compared to the half a tera-byte on the main one.  I still need to look into other thing like stored-procedures and caching, but right now I'm focusing on the code and query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prevent duplicated register:

```
INSERT INTO Customers ( CustomerId )
   SELECT 1 AS CustomerId 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1 FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = 1 );
```

One way to avoid the null = null is false

```
 SELECT * 
       FROM Customers 
      WHERE Name = @Name
        AND ISNULL(BillingAccount, '_') = ISNULL(@BillingAccount, '_')
        AND ISNULL(ShippingAccount, '_') = ISNULL(@ShippingAccount, '_')
```

Comment: Hi Marcelo. I see that you're fairly new to SO, and are probably wondering how others get their posts formatted so nicely.  See here for info on that: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: This won't work if  `@BillingAccount` is null but BillingAccount isn't.

Comment: Hogan yes it will; I just tried it out.  I want the expression to evaluate to false if @BillingAddress is null but BillingAddress isn't, because that isn't a match.  My problem was that I needed the expression to evaluate to true if both are null and this does that.

Answer (score 2):

Use IsNull on both Sides

```
  WHERE Name = @Name
    AND IsNull(BillingAccount, -1) = 
            Coalesce(@BillingAccount, BillingAccount, -1)
    AND IsNull(ShippingAccount, -1)  =
            Coalesce(@ShippingAccount, ShippingAccount, -1)
```

Or include check if both parameter and field are BOTH null

```
   WHERE Name = @Name
    AND (Coalesce(@BillingAccount, BillingAccount) is Null Or
       BillingAccount = Coalesce(@BillingAccount, BillingAccount, -1))
    AND Coalesce(@ShippingAccount, ShippingAccount) is Null Or
       ShippingAccount = Coalesce(@ShippingAccount, ShippingAccount)
```

Comment: had to give it to Marcelo.  You don't need to use Coalesce; IsNull is fine.  Also I get an error when the last parameter of IsNull or Coalesce is and integer, since the field type is varchar.  -1 needs to be '-1' or some other string that isn't going to show up in an address field.

Comment: @Michael,  np, I like to think that generally, we're here to help, not to get points!  And you're right, the type of the "default value" has to match, I didn't know what type it was... I guessed, assuming an account identifier would be a number.

Answer (score 1):

another way

```
 WHERE Name = @Name
 AND ( BillingAccount = @BillingAccount or  @BillingAccount is null )
 AND ( ShippingAccount = @ShippingAccount or  @ShippingAccount is null)
```

based on your comment

```
where Name = @Name
and(
(BillingAccount = @BillingAccount and ShippingAccount = @ShippingAccount)or
(@BillingAccount is null and @ShippingAccount is null)
)
```

Comment: This won't work.  Remember the result of an expression (besides is null or is not null) with null fails.

Comment: It runs but isn't quite what I want.  It would have to be ...AND(BillingAddress = @BillingAddress OR (BillingAddress IS NULL AND @'BillingAddress IS NULL))

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
 SELECT * 
       FROM Customers 
      WHERE Name = @Name
        AND ISNULL(BillingAccount, '_') = ISNULL(@BillingAccount, ISNULL(BillingAccount, '_'))
        AND ISNULL(ShippingAccount, '_') = ISNULL(@ShippingAccount, ISNULL(ShippingAccount, '_'))
```

Answer (score -1):

An example of why COALESCE is better than ISNULL

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
 WHERE Name = @Name
 AND COALESCE(BillingAccount, 0) = COALESCE(@BillingAccount, BillingAccount, 0)
 AND COALESCE(ShippingAccount,0) = COALESCE(@ShippingAccount, ShippingAccount, 0)
```